# how do i make this python script go through s3 object keys and specify which bucket is empty if no keys exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, python-3.8

This function prints list of s3 buckets as well as their object keys. How to make this function print the list of empty buckets only?

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

def empty_s3():
#This will print list of all buckets
  print("\nList of S3 buckets:")
  for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name)
#This will print s3 bucket object keys
    for object in bucket.objects.all():
      print(object)
```

Comment: What's wrong with the current script? Any errors?

Comment: No errors with this script. It prints the list of buckets and its objects, but I need to print just the list of empty buckets.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check the number of objects:

```py
import boto3

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')

for bucket in s3_resource.buckets.all():
    objects = list(bucket.objects.all())

    # Empty bucket?
    if len(objects) == 0:
        print(bucket.name)
```